# Confusion regarding association relationship in UML

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram, conceptual-model

To start off, I'm really confused between the association relationship between classes in UML, as there is unidirectional and bidirectional association.

I've drawn up a simple example, which is:

[image]

But I've looked up some examples online and i found out that most examples used the unidirectional association between the Patient class and the Doctor class.

When i interpret the diagram, i would interpret it as so where "the patient class knows about the doctor class but the doctor class does not know about the patient class." But it still didn't make much sense as in why would a doctor class not know about the patient class?

Could anyone please explain to me in a more detailed manner? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Interpretation of your diagram**

Your diagram says that:

- a `Doctor` can have several `Patients`, but has at least one (multiplicity `1..n`)
- a `Patient` can have several `Doctors`, and can have none (multiplicity `0..n`)
- a `Doctor` `attends to` a `Patient`
- a `Patient` object can find the associated `Doctor` objects (navigability arrow at the end of the association)
- nothing is said about whether a `Doctor` can find his/her `Patient`s (absence of any navigability indication on the other end of the association). So we don't know

**Potential problems in your diagram**

First, there is an obvious confusion about where to place the multiplicity, because a newly appointed doctor may have no patient when he/she opens his/her practice.  Conversely,  a patient without any doctor is not a patient but a healthy person. So keep in mind that the **multiplicity is next to the target**: so `1..n` is about the number of `Patients` for a `Doctor` and not the contrary.

Then the triangle near the label "attends to" indicates the sense of reading.  Here it is `Doctor` `attends to` `Patient`.  <strike>But in general, it's patient who attend to doctors.  So the triangle should be on the other side and symetric to the one you have drawn.</strike>*(sorry [this last point was ok](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/attend-attend-to.223967/), I can still improve my english ;-)*

**The question of navigability**

Now to the [navigability](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability).  The diagram makes explicit that a `Patient` knows and can find the associated `Doctor`s. In a hospital registration system, it makes sense when a patient arrives and doesn't remember the name of the doctor to lookup for the potential doctors.

But your diagram says nothing about the opposite navigability.  This is left "unspecified".  The diagram could clarify the situation either by indicating a cross on the link (i.e. no navigability), or an arrow (navigability).

Maybe there is a reverse navigability but it's not explicit (because the drawer assumed that it was so obvious).  Maybe there is indeed no navigability in that direction. So the `Doctor` doesn't know its `Patients`.  This could make sense for example if the [hospital registration system](http://studyyypointtt.blogspot.com/2013/05/uml-diagrams-for-hospital-management.html) consider that the Patient is the Patient of the hospital and the interaction has always to go via the administration.  The `Doctor` may in such case have a navigable association to an [`Appointment`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23593667/3723423) that has a navigable association to the `Patient` or other kind of ***indirect navigability***.

Comment: very nice and complete answer!

Comment: I agree, that this is a very complete answer. As a matter of fact you use the same elements/connectors in different detail during design phase. The OP's diagram looks like being in earlier design phase. So what needs to be said (direction, ownership, role names, multiplicity, etc.) also strongly depends on the design phase itself. Just as a thought. No need to expand on the answer as this will lead to just another UML book ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The terms "unidirectional association" and "bidirectional association" are not used/defined in UML. Rather, they refer to the way an association is implemented in OOP with either one reference property or a pair of mutually inverse reference properties (see also [this tutorial](https://web-engineering.info/tech/JsFrontendApp/bidirectional-association-tutorial.html)).

In a conceptual model, we are not concerned with questions like "does the patient class know about the doctor class?". Rather, we just model the fact that there is an association between two classes.

The question if, with respect to an association between `A` and `B`, `A` "knows about" `B` is better formulated as: do instances of `A` need direct access to instances of `B`? In that case, we would add a reference property `A::b` for being able to directly access/retrieve all associated `B` objects. This can be expressed in a class diagram by placing a small dot at the `B` side of the association (called an "association end ownership dot" in UML).

It depends on the requirements of the app you are going to build if bidirectional access, which comes with a computational price, is really needed.

Comment: The unidirectional/bidirectional refers to the navigability, which **is** defined in UML. Since v2.5 they also added the dot notation to indicate whether or not there is a property referencing the other side, but these are two different things. In this case the question is about navigability (arrowhead), not about referencing properties (dot notation)

Comment: Concerning your first claim: just search in the spec - they do not even mention the terms "unidirectional" and "bidirectional"! Concerning your second claim: the question is not about navigability, but about which class "knows about" the other one.

Comment: Yes, but these just common vocabulary to indicate the direction of arrows. I think OP is asking about navigability, not the dot notation.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Given what OMG says about DirectedRelationship on p.42 I'd concur with the statement that "it's not defined". It totally leaves open what the "Directed" part of the term means.